# Make text overflow horizontally into column

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I have a webpage with text that is not allowed to scroll vertically.

This means that when text overflows I need it to overflow horizontally. What I am trying to do is separate it into columns. Basically, as the section of text gets too tall for the height of its parent it would form columns like this:

[image: Text Overflow Example]

I know that the columns can easily be achieved with an HTML table. However, I don't know how many columns I am going to need, partly because the height of the parent is subject to change, and partly because I need it to work when things like the font-size change. I can think of a couple ways to do this with some javascript, but I was wondering:

Is there any way to get this behavior with just HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text can flow horizontally if you use the `column` properties.

If you go through http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model you will see there are two ways of implmenting this. The first one is that you specify the `width` of a column using `column-width`. The other one is where you specify the number of columns using `column-count`.

As you mentioned in the question:

> However, I don't know how many columns I am going to need, partly because the height of the parent is subject to change, and partly because I need it to work when things like the font-size change.

You will have to do calculations to either find the width or the number of columns.

I have this very vague idea for a formula based on the available width for the text container, then use the font size and see how many characters can be accommodated in one line. Further, you can use the line height to find the number of lines that can fit in one column and hence find an approximate width/count.

Answer (score 0):

This css code will help you.
-webkit-column-count:3;-webkit-column-gap:25px;text-align:justify;

Answer (score -2):

I found what you are searching.`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts`
It`s css3

Comment: CSS3 `column-count` will work only if he knows the number of columns he needs.

Comment: Oh. yes sorry for my inattention. It can help you! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Answer (score -2):

use css `"overflow:scroll-y"` property.....

Comment: the `overflow` property will only stop the overflow, but he is looking for a dynamic column creation.